# How to Format a web.response stream before saving it to a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am collecting info using web.response method as a web crawler.  I collect it to a string and then save it to a text file .Then I search that text file using regular expression. 
Now the problem is when I search that text file using regular expression I am not able to do it properly because there are many random newlines in the text file.

My question is "Is there a way that the XML (HTML) document I get by web.response method can be formatted properly before saving it to text file , so that there are no random spaces and newlines in the text. I can not even post an unformatted HTML here otherwise I would have done it.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet might hate you for doing this, but you could transform the string if you have predefined criteria, such as:

```
var formattedHtml = html.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,Seems very thoughtful but when i tried it , it appears as if those are not newline characters they could be just random number of spaces.What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem. But from performance point of view it is a `bad solution`.

Perform following actions on the response

1. Extract the content between `>` and `<` symbols and perform a Trim white space operation
2. Remove all the remaining new lines if present

Another `better solution` will be using a better RegEx for searching the string